# Swiftmailer: Sends twice, checked all the usual culprits

Tags: php, swiftmailer

So here is the code. It only happens with some users but it happens often enough to be irritating. I have checked all the usual culprits(IE extra send commands etc)

I am also getting an error when the script finished that reads `Warning: Unknown: Error occurred while closing statement in Unknown on line` which obviously tell me absolutely nothing or if the two issues are related.

```
<?php

$row = array();
$sql = "SELECT username, email, role FROM newsletter";
require_once '../includes/db_connect.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
} 
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
    foreach($row as $key => $val) { 
        if($val === 'Not Found' || $val == ''){
        continue;
        }else {
        $c[$key] = $val; 
        }   
    } 
    $row[] = $c;
}

$htmlEmail = 'blah blah blah';

$textEmail = "blah blah bah";

require_once '../lib/swift_required.php';
// Create the Mailer using any Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
  Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.****.com', 25)
  ->setUsername('sales@*****.com')
  ->setPassword('********')
);

// Rate limit to 100 emails per-minute
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(
    50, Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE
));

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

// Give the message a subject
$message->setSubject('Sorry about that we had a glitch!');

// Set the From address with an associative array
$message->setFrom(array('sales@*****.com' => 'Auction Hunter Pro'));

// Give it a body
$message->setBody($textEmail);

// And optionally an alternative body
$message->addPart($htmlEmail, 'text/html');

 foreach($row as $user) {
     if(is_array($user) && !empty($user['username'])){
         $message->setTo($user['email']);
         $mailer->send($message);
     }else { continue; }
  }
```

Comment: do you have access to the mail server logs?

Comment: No and it is my BIGGEST complaint against my hosting company! I can call them, but at this poing I don't even know what to ask them to look for... :(

Comment: i do a lot of work with sending mail, but  with out mail server log access, its going to be real hard to debug.

Comment: I am going to see if they can send them to me this is ridiculous, what hosting provider doesn't provide logs...

Comment: back to the drawing board, they wont send the log because it contains data from the whole server not just my domain. argh!

Comment: a VPS is quite cheap now ;)

Comment: Turned out it was in the query itself. Or more correctly when we converted the results to an array it because msqlnd was not enabled we were getting partially full arrays. one with just the email and one with the username and email addy. I thought I had accounted for that. I evidently I hadn't. Because it was an in house script I just we back to a plain mysqli query and we're done with it.

Comment: thanks for letting us know